# Angular 2 call parents component from nested TreeView directive component

Tags: angular

I am using TreeView Component borrowed from [Torgeir Helgevold's post](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/recursive-treeview-in-angular-2.0) or [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/e1SxsnrxrW6adoHotai9?p=preview). I try to call parents method from TreeView when is double click on any node but it works only for top node. Here is what I have so far
Parents Component

```
 @Component({
    selector: 'hierarchy-mgmt',
    template: ' <div class="accounts-container col col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <h2>Managed Accounts</h2>
              <tree-item-renderer [account]="commonNodeModel.rootNode"
                                  (editing)="editStart($event)">
              </tree-item-renderer>
    </div>
               ',
    providers: [TreeItemRendererComponent]
 })
 export class HierarchyMgmtComponent implements OnInit {    
    //... constructor and other code
    ngOnInit(): void {
            this.nodeService.getNodesForUser()
        .then((rootNode: CustomerNode) => {
            this.commonNodeModel.RootNode = rootNode;
            this.commonNodeModel.SelectedNode = rootNode;
            return this.nodeService.getNodeValidationDetails();
        })
        .then((nodeValidationDetails: NodeValidationDetails) => {
            this.commonNodeModel.NodeValidationDetails = nodeValidationDetails;
            this.hierarchyLoaded = true;
            console.log(this.commonUserModel.usersForSelectedNode);
        })
        .catch(
            Utils.callFailureWithResponseDataFunction((failureResponse: any, hasBeenDisplayedToUser: any) => {
                this.notifyService.notifyUserIfNecessary(hasBeenDisplayedToUser, "There was a problem initialising this page. Please contact Support");
            }));
    }
    editStart(node: CustomerNode) {
        this.commonNodeModel.EditingNode = node;
    }
   // ... other code
 }
```

TreeItemRenderer Component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tree-item-renderer',
    template: `
        <div class="node">
            <span class="node-input" [ngClass]="getSelectedClass()" (dblclick)="edit(account)" (click)="spanSelected()"
                  title="{{account.name}}" [innerHtml]="account.name"></span>
            <input type="text" class="editField" [ngModel]="account.name" placeholder="Enter an Account Name">
            <ul class="node-list">
                <li *ngFor="let account of account.children">
                    <tree-item-renderer [account]="account"  (editing)="editStart($event)"></tree-item-renderer>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    `
})

export class TreeItemRendererComponent implements OnInit {

    @Output()
    editing: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

    edit(node: any) {
        this.editing.emit(node);
    }
    // ... other codes 
}
```

The problem is that child node has referent to *TreeItemRenderer* component and **not** to *HierarchyMgmtComponent*. Guess in *TreeItemRenderer* component needs something like *(editing)="parents.editStart($event)"*. Can anyone help please. Thank you.

In addition, I am aware of that *HierarchyMgmtComponent* component can be injected into *TreeItemRenderer* component, "which I have tried it and it is working", but it is not what I am looking for.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/LLCBJUZFH1ySLSGzBoW3?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call the parents method from any level down within the hierarchy, you will have to wire up event handlers all the way down the chain.

See this plunker: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hIQz2DPrVIA4RuhqsT5N)

To wire up the nodes as a parent to their children, use the same syntax as you did for the top level. In the TreeView component, add an event handler method (`childObserverMethod`) and in the TreeView class, add a method handler that emits the same event as the parent is wired to (`this.myParentObserverMethod.emit(node)`):

```
@Component ({
  selector: 'tree-view',
  directives: [TreeView],
  template: `
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="#node of treeData" >
      <span (click)="myClickMethod($event, node)">{{node.name}}</span>
      <tree-view [treeData]="node.subnodes" (myParentObserverMethod)="childObserverMethod($event)"></tree-view>
    </li>
</ul>
  `
})
export class TreeView {
  @Input() treeData: [];

  @Output()
  myParentObserverMethod: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

    myClickMethod(event, node)
    {
      this.myParentObserverMethod.emit(node);
      console.log("child - " + node.name)
    }

    childObserverMethod(node)
    {
      this.myParentObserverMethod.emit(node);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

You could re-use the myClickMethod rather than create another method, e.g.

```
@Component ({
  selector: 'tree-view',
  directives: [TreeView],
  template: `
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="#node of treeData" >
      <span (click)="myClickMethod($event, node)">{{node.name}}</span>
      <tree-view [treeData]="node.subnodes" (myParentObserverMethod)="myClickMethod($event)"></tree-view>
    </li>
</ul>
  `
})
export class TreeView {
  @Input() treeData: [];

  @Output()
  myParentObserverMethod: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

    myClickMethod(event, node)
    {
      this.myParentObserverMethod.emit(node);
      console.log("child - " + node.name)
    }
}
```